# Configuring multiple type of data with one filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have multiple type of data that I put logstash to configure it. I write filter but that filter only works for some of my data that is exactly suitable with my filter context. How can I type a filter that can configure all my data?

This is my filter:

```
filter {


   if[method]=="POST"
{
  grok {
     match => {
       '"%{DATA:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\] "%{WORD:method} %{DATA:type}?%{WORD:page}=%{DATA:page_size}&%{DATA: referrer_page_size}=%{DATA:total_page} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}" %{NUMBER:response_code} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) "%{DATA:connection}//%{DATA:search}/%{DATA:try2}/\?%{DATA:typeof_query}=%{DATA:looked_for}" "%{DATA:agent}" "%{DATA:http_x_forwarded_for}" "%{DATA:country}"'
     }
  }


}
}
```

This is my first data:

```
IP Adress - - [01/Jul/2019:15:36:18 +0300] "POST /search?page=1&page_size=25 HTTP/1.1" 200 78 "https://dofo.com/search/?contains=pflichtteilberatung" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0" "IP Adress" "DE"
```

This is my second data:

```
IP Adress - - [01/Jul/2019:12:46:26 +0300] "POST /search?page=64&page_size=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 3171 "https://try.com/search/?on_sale=y&price_max=3000&sale_type=1,3&extension=com&length=1-15&hyphen=n&number=n&idn=n&cdate_min=19971105&sort=cdate_a&page_s=100&page=64" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" "IP Adress" "BD"
```

This is my third data:

```
IP Adress - - [01/Jul/2019:03:09:55 +0300] "POST /search?page=1&page_size=100 HTTP/1.1" 200 2661 "https://try.com/search/?contains=real&page_s=100" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36" "IP Adress" "LT"
```

I want to parse them after `"https://try.com/search/?"` value. For the first data I need `"contains"` field with `"pflichtteilberatung"` value
For the second data I need `"on_sale"` field with `"y"` value and `"price_max"` field with `"3000"` value .....
For the third I need `"contains"` field with `"real"` value and `"page_s"` field with `"100"` value.

Is it possible to make it in logstash filter?

Comment: Hi Ahmet. Is it just these three types or URLs that you're expecting, or is there potentially many more?

Comment: Actually, there are many more. These are just 3 of them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could achieve this with Logstash filters, however I suspect the layout of the query string could vary outside of your control in the future, causing you to forever be testing and changing your grok filters.

If I take your second data line as an example, there is a lot of different parameters in that query string, and I am assuming the position of those parameters could also vary. This would mean creating a number of filters or [patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns) to account for all of these possible variants if you want those values to be store in their own matching fields. If that data was to change suddenly, you would then have to update your logstash filters and patterns and it would become an administrative nightmare. You would also lose data that doesn't match these filters unless you're catching non-matched patterns that you could review later. [Here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-can-i-find-unmatched-logs-with-pattern-grok/101302) is an example of this.

This doesn't achieve what you want, but it would be easier to catch the entire query string as a whole, and if you're sending this data into something like elasticsearch, you could still filter for those parameters in the query string field. Below is how I would do it; and it was tested using this handy [tool](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match).

```
%{IPORHOST:IP_address} %{USER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\] "%{WORD:method} %{DATA:type}?page=%{DATA:page_no}&page_size=%{DATA:referrer_page_size} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}" %{NUMBER:response_code} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-) "%{DATA:connection}://%{DATA:search}" "%{DATA:agent}" "%{DATA:http_x_forwarded_for}" "%{DATA:country}"
```

Comment: I am not sure about your answer sir but thank you for your respond. I used another filter which is called kv and separated my referrer value with "&". It created related field and typed its value.